# Mysterious line, used to require html templates in Webpack: templates.keys().forEach(templates)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I want to import html templates into Webpack bundle with ngTemplate-loader and html-template-loader and found two lines of code, used for that purpose, in another project:

```
const templates = require.context(__dirname, true, /\.html$/);
templates.keys().forEach(templates);
```

The first line is clear to me - it recursively requires all the html files under current directory, adding them to $templateCache.

But the second line is a total mistery for me. What's the point of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`templates.keys()` will return array of paths to matched files:

```
['./file1.js', './file2.js'].forEach(templates);
```

Then `forEach` will invoke `templates` function (which is `require` with context setted to `__dirname`) for each file:

```
templates('./file1.js');
templates('./file2.js');
```

or:

```
require('./file1.js'); // this files will be searched relative to __dirname
require('./file2.js');
```

Comment: First line is not requires html files. It creates `require` function with context.